# Why does getGeneratedKeys() return "GENERATED_KEY" as column name?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm playing with the JDBC/MySQL 5.1. I created an `insert` query to insert some data into a table and want to return the generated key from the newly created row. However, when I go to reference the column by "id" which is my PK and auto-increment column.

```
PreparedStatement ps = St0rm.getInstance().getDatabase("main")
        .prepare("INSERT INTO quests (name,minlevel,start_npc,end_npc) VALUES(?,?,?,?)", true); // creates a prepared statement with flag RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS

// ...

int affected = ps.executeUpdate();
ResultSet keys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
if (affected > 0 && keys.next()) {
   St0rm.getInstance().getLogger().warning(String.format("ID Column Name: %s", keys.getMetaData().getColumnName(1))); // says the column name is: GENERATED_KEY

   q = new Quest(keys.getInt(1)); // column index from the generated key, no error thrown.

   q = new Quest(keys.getInt("id")); // actual column name, line throws a SQLException
   // ...
}
```

So, my question: **Why does `ResultSet.getGeneratedKeys` use `GENERATED_KEY` as the column name?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You shouldn't retrieve these columns by name. Only by index, since
>   there can only ever be one column with MySQL and auto_increments that
>   returns value(s) that can be exposed by Statement.getGeneratedKeys().
>
> Currently the MySQL server doesn't return information directly that
>   would make the ability to retrieve these columns by name in an
>   efficient manner possible, which is why I'm marking this as "to be
>   fixed later", since we can, once the server returns the information in
>   a way that the driver can use.

From [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18409) (in 2006!).