# The "route_id" not found

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to get the `id` of the inserted raw in the `routes` table. Currently I am getting the error  `Column 'route_id' not found` but the route and direction are being inserted in the table before Why am I getting this error?

**Code:**

```
DatabaseMetaData dbm = con.getMetaData();

        ResultSet routesTables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "routes",
                null);
        int route_id;
        if (routesTables.next()) {

            PreparedStatement prepRoutesInsert = con.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO routes(direction, route)"
                            + "VALUES( ?, ?)",
                    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

            prepRoutesInsert.setString(1, direction);
            prepRoutesInsert.setInt(2, route);

            prepRoutesInsert.executeUpdate();

            try (ResultSet generatedKeys = prepRoutesInsert
                    .getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                    int id = generatedKeys.getInt("route_id");
                    System.out.println("The id is: " + id);
                }

            }
```

**routes table structure:**

```
   stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS routes ("
                + "route_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
                + "direction VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, "
                + "route INT(11) NOT NULL )");
```

**Screenshot of geratedKeys variable:**

[image]

**Edit:**
When I query it like this I am getting the `route_id` but of the all raws in the routes table:

```
             PreparedStatement prepRoutesInsert2 =
             con.prepareStatement(
             "SELECT route_id from routes",
             Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
             ResultSet rs = prepRoutesInsert2.executeQuery();
             while(rs.next()){
             int route_id2 = rs.getInt("route_id");
             System.out.println(route_id2);
             }
```

Comment: what is your table structure?

Comment: please see my updated question code.

Comment: could you try to put a debug point on `prepRoutesInsert.executeUpdate();` and see what is saved in the db?

Comment: I have debugged it and as I said before a new route and direction are being inseted. I can see it in the db. Is that what did you ask?

Comment: See if this is applicable to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224228/preparedstatement-with-statement-return-generated-keys

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
int id = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
```

instead.

The comment posted in response to [this MySQL bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18409) says that:

> You shouldn't retrieve these columns by name. Only by index, since there can only ever be one column with MySQL and auto_increments that returns value(s) that can be exposed by Statement.getGeneratedKeys().

If you really want to, you can use

```
int id = generatedKeys.getInt("GENERATED_KEY");
```

instead, and it will work, but I wouldn't recommend it.  [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867521/why-does-getgeneratedkeys-return-generated-key-as-column-name) asks why the name `GENERATED_KEY` is used, and its only answer quotes from the same bug I linked to above.